# How to retrieve value from a select box?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

In html code:

```
<select name="123023d">
 <option value="default">Not Share</option>
 <option value="read">Read Only</option>
 <option value="edit">Editable</option>
</select>
```

In php code:

```
$rights=$_POST['123023d'];
```

Why i can not retrieve the value of this select box?

```
Notice: Undefined index: 123023d in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\list\add.php on line 87
```

Thank you.

I am sure it is in the form and it is a post method. It is located after     `foreach ($result as $set)`  as you can see i draw some sql value to generate that select box and the name of the select box is userID

Whole part:

```
<form id="addlist" method="post" action="add.php" >
<h1>Create your new subscriber list</h1> 
<p>Create a new list before adding subscriber <label class="right"><em class="dot">*</em> indicates required</label></p>

<label><em class="dot">*</em> List name:
<span class="small">Add your list name</span>
</label>
<input id="lname" name="lname" class="required" />

<div class="spacer"></div>

<label>Reminder:
<span class="small">Remind the details of your list</span>
</label>
<textarea id="creminder" name="creminder" cols="52" ></textarea>

<div class="spacer"></div>


<div class="spacer"></div>

<p>Email me when ...</p> 
<label>People subscribe:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="1">
<label>People unsubscribe:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="unsubscribe" value="1">
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

</br>

<div id="stylized" class="myform">

<p>Permission Setting ...</p>

<label>Open to other users:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="public" value="1">
Or
<div class="spacer"></div>

Select the permission for individual user:

<?
$sql =
    "SELECT  UserID,Name,Rights,Position
    FROM     user
    WHERE UserID != ?
    AND Rights != 'Admin'
    ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));

$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();

if ($num_rows != 0){
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>

<table width="100%" class="display" id="viewSub">
<thead>
<tr>
<th field="col1" width="40%">Name:</th>
<th field="col2" width="40%">Position:</th>
<th field="col2" width="20%">Permission:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?
foreach ($result as $set) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$set['Name']."</td><td>".$set['Position']."</td><td><select name=".$set['UserID']."><option value='default'>Not Share</option><option value='read'>Read Only</option><option value='edit'>Editable</option></select></td></tr>";
}
?>
</tbody> 
</table>

<?
}
else
echo "There is no another user in this system";
?>


<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
```

add.php  which is the form and the result process

```
<?
include("../connection/conn.php");
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
print_r($_POST);
exit();
if (!isset($_POST['subscribe']))
$_POST['subscribe']=0;
if (!isset($_POST['unsubscribe']))
$_POST['unsubscribe']=0;
if (!isset($_POST['public']))
$_POST['public']=0;

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



try {

    $listName = $_POST['lname'];
    $listRemindSub = $_POST['subscribe'];
    $creator = $_SESSION['username'];
    $listRemindUnSub = $_POST['unsubscribe'];
    $isPublic = $_POST['public'];
    $listReminder = $_POST['creminder'];


    $query="INSERT INTO list (ListID,ListName,Creator,IsRemindSub,IsRemindUnSub,IsPublic,CreateDate,Reminder) VALUES ('',?,?,?,?,?,CURDATE(),?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);


    $stmt->bindParam(1, $listName , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $creator, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $listRemindSub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $listRemindUnSub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $isPublic, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $listReminder, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();


}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    }


try {
    $lastID=$conn->lastInsertId();
    $query="INSERT INTO require_attributes (ReqID,ListID,Attribute,Tag) VALUES ('',$lastID,'Email','{email}')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $query="INSERT INTO require_attributes (ReqID,ListID,Attribute,Tag) VALUES ('',$lastID,'FirstName','{fname}')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $query="INSERT INTO require_attributes (ReqID,ListID,Attribute,Tag) VALUES ('',$lastID,'LastName','{lname}')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    } 

try{
$sql = '
SELECT UserID
FROM user
WHERE Rights != ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('admin'));
$result= $stmt->fetchAll();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }

foreach ($result as $set)
{   
if ($set['UserID']==$_SESSION['username'])
$rights='edit';
else
{$rights=$_POST[$set["UserID"]];
$rights=$_POST['123023d'];}



if ($rights != 'default' || $set['UserID']==$_SESSION['username'] || $_POST['public']==0)
{ 
$user=$set['UserID'];
try {
    $query="INSERT INTO user_list(UserID,ListID,UserRights) VALUES ('$user',$lastID,'$rights')";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    $conn->rollBack();
    }  
}
}

$conn = null;

?>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">You have created a list. By default Mail Address, First Name , Last Name is in your list. Add more field if you want. <a href='add.php'>Back</a></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<?
}else{?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style type="text/css">
      @import "../plugin/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css";
      @import "../plugin/easyui/themes/icon.css";
      @import "../style/form.css";
      @import "../plugin/datatable/media/css/demo_page.css";
      @import "../plugin/datatable/media/css/demo_table.css";
</style>
<script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/datatable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="../plugin/jquery.form.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addlist").validate();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#viewSub').dataTable();
    } );
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<form id="addlist" method="post" action="add.php" >
<h1>Create your new subscriber list</h1> 
<p>Create a new list before adding subscriber <label class="right"><em class="dot">*</em> indicates required</label></p>

<label><em class="dot">*</em> List name:
<span class="small">Add your list name</span>
</label>
<input id="lname" name="lname" class="required" />

<div class="spacer"></div>

<label>Reminder:
<span class="small">Remind the details of your list</span>
</label>
<textarea id="creminder" name="creminder" cols="52" ></textarea>

<div class="spacer"></div>


<div class="spacer"></div>

<p>Email me when ...</p> 
<label>People subscribe:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="1">
<label>People unsubscribe:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="unsubscribe" value="1">
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>

</br>

<div id="stylized" class="myform">

<p>Permission Setting ...</p>

<label>Open to other users:</label> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="public" value="1">
Or
<div class="spacer"></div>

Select the permission for individual user:

<?
$sql =
    "SELECT  UserID,Name,Rights,Position
    FROM     user
    WHERE UserID != ?
    AND Rights != 'Admin'
    ";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));

$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();

if ($num_rows != 0){
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>

<table width="100%" class="display" id="viewSub">
<thead>
<tr>
<th field="col1" width="40%">Name:</th>
<th field="col2" width="40%">Position:</th>
<th field="col2" width="20%">Permission:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?
foreach ($result as $set) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$set['Name']."</td><td>".$set['Position']."</td><td><select name=".$set['UserID']."><option value='default'>Not Share</option><option value='read'>Read Only</option><option value='edit'>Editable</option></select></td></tr>";
}
?>
</tbody> 
</table>

<?
}
else
echo "There is no another user in this system";
?>


<input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
<div class="spacer"></div>

</form>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
<?
try{
$sql = '
    SELECT   *
    FROM     list,user_list
    WHERE    user_list.UserID=?
    AND list.ListID=user_list.ListID
';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$result= $stmt->fetchAll();
$num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    die ($e->getMessage().'<a href="add.php"> Back</a>'); 
    }
$conn = null;
if ($num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<div style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">You have not created any list yet.</div>';}
else {
    echo '<h1>Your Subscriber List</h1> <p>You have created '.$num_rows.' list(s).</p>';
foreach ($result as $set) 
{
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">List Name : '.$set['FromName'].'</div><br>';
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">Subscriber : </div><br>';
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold;">Create Date : '.$set['CreateDate'].'</div><br>';
echo '<hr>';
}}
    ?>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>

<?
}
?>
```

Comment: have you checked that the form has method="POST"?

Comment: use print_r($_POST); to see what request actually conatins.

Comment: i don't see the select box result is post, it is the root of the problem

Comment: Please take a look in the whole part, since it is in the form and the method is post, i can grantee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the method you are using to submit the form. There are two general ways

1. GET Method `<form method="GET" ... >`

   This is generally retrieved by using

   ```
   echo $_GET['123023d'];
   ```
2. POST Method `<form method="POST" ... >`
   This is generally retrieved by using

   ```
   echo $_POST['123023d'];
   ```

If no method is defined, by default, it will be submitted using `GET` method so, use

```
$rights=$_GET['123023d'];
```

---

#### Update

I found your problem, there is no quotes in the title of select box

```
<select name=".$set['UserID'].">
```

Change it to this. You have to provide the quotes and escape them as well.

```
<select name=\"".$set['UserID']."\">
```

#### Update 2

<sub>Credit to @zerkms</sub>

The another problem was starting the name with a numeric value instead of a alphabetically character.

```
<select name="123023d">
```

Make sure you dont start with numbers like

```
<select name="a123023d">
```

Comment: thanks, it is in the form and i use the correct way already, it still hasn't post

Comment: @user782104, you notice that `action="add.php"` submits the form to add.php right. Are you coding on same page? By your update on the post, it doesn't seems so. Show the code of `add.php` as well, if its different.

Comment: @user782104, just that to confirm everything is perfect, choose a different name of the select box. `d123023` may be. Just to confirm it is not happening due to incorrect definition

Comment: add.php is the form and the further processing  , that means, it is where the form locate and it is where the form result post to

Comment: I have added the whole php at it , you can skip the sql thing and look into the form and post result directly

Comment: I have change the name of select box, but it does not post . So i am confused because i put in in the form already.

Comment: @user782104, what is the output of the `print_r($_POST)` at the top of your code.

Comment: Array ( [lname] => tt [creminder] => [submit] => Submit )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8662/discussion-between-starx-and-user782104)

Comment: ok i have enter the room

Answer (score 0):

> How to retrieve value from a select box?

it is stored in the $_POST['123023d'] or $_GET['123023d'] variable depends on the method used.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a 'post' request , use :

```
$rights=$_POST['123023d'];
```

For 'get' requests :

```
$rights=$_GET['123023d'];
```